# Bootstrap navbar collapse issue with multiple headers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

here is my code.

```
<header class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top wet-asphalt">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse">
                <a href="tel:9XXXXXXXXX">Call now!</a>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse **navbar-collapse**">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-top:0px;">
                <li><a href="tel:9XXXXXXXXX">9XXXXXXXXX</a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:example@gmail.com">mail us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<header class="navbar navbar-inverse wet-asphalt" role="banner" style="margin-top: -46px; border-radius:0px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" style="margin-top: 25px;">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse **navbar-collapse**">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

When I click on second header menu, while viewing this on a Mobile device. It triggers both `navbar-collapse`. When I remove `navbar-collapse` class from first header it disappears.

I dont want the class to be removed from my first header too and also dont want it to collapse.
Please help me to sort out. I am new with Bootstrap.

Comment: Make two function, one is first header and second is second header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to keep the links in the first `navbar` exposed at all times while keeping the standard `collapse` function for the section just use two separate navbars but remove the `collapse` function (the `navbar-header` section) from the first. Then you can surround both navs with the `navbar-fixed-top` class.

*The only CSS that needs to be applied is to keep your first navs links inline on device sizes.

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  padding-top: 120px;
}
.navbar-inverse.navbar-top ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar-fixed-top">

  <div class="navbar-inverse navbar-static-top navbar-top">
    <div class="container">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="#">123 456-7890</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Mail Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/50x25/fff/fff">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home </a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>

<div class="container">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because their `data-target` are same. Give them both different, for example `data-target=".navbar-collapse-1"` and `data-target=".navbar-collapse-2"`

And each `data-target` should point to the corresponding container class. First div will have first class `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse-1">` and second one should have the other one  `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse-2">`

Here's your working code.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<header class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top wet-asphalt">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse-1">
                <a href="tel:9XXXXXXXXX">Call now!</a>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-top:0px;">
                <li><a href="tel:9XXXXXXXXX">9XXXXXXXXX</a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:example@gmail.com">mail us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<header class="navbar navbar-inverse wet-asphalt" role="banner" style="margin-top: 150px; border-radius:0px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse-2" style="margin-top: 25px;">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse-2">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```